# Java hibernate multiple one to many and many to one relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am doing a spring boot web application project. And I am at my database layer, trying to test it. And by getting errors i got this question, is this really possible to have multiple one to many and many to one relationships on one entity?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand

Comment: Hello @Ignas Sungaila and welcome to Stack Overflow. Help us help you by reading "How do I ask a good question?" in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, you can refer the below use case:

```
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Set<Employees> employees;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="depatment_id", nullable=false)
    private Department department;

    public Employee() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand, but If I understand good you have a entity that have multiple relation with other entities. `You can change Any UML class diagram to entities.`

Yes you can do that.

```
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
public class Classes{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="prof")
    private List<Professor> prof;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    private List<Student> student;    
    // getters and setters
}
```